# Making a div to show upwards, while pushing up and down the siblings div

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I would like, upon a button click, to make a div to show up upwards, while pushing other div on its top and bottom upwards and downwards respectively. 
Following there's the link to a video of how it should look like:

[https://streamable.com/ynnvn][1]

I've tried many jQuery methods like slideDown(), slideUp(), animate()... without success.
Regarding the JavaScript part I tried to animate the form (that must be shown) upwards, while moving the div with class "widget" downwards. The problem is, the widget moves down too quickly, the whole animation is not fluid and setting a timing in ms doesn't help  Any advice would be appreciated, many thanks!

```js
$("#anmelden").click(() => {
  $("#my_form").slideUp(1000);
});

$("#zufall").click(() => {
  $("#my_form").show("slide", {
    direction: "down"
  });
  $(".widget").animate({
    "top": "3.0rem"
  });
});
```

```css
.widget {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 19vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 4.5rem;
  margin: 4.8rem auto;
}

.container {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 56rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 19vw;
  height: 40vh;
}

form {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Title</div>
  <form action="submit" id="my_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="text_input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Passwort" class="text_input">
  </form>
  <div class="widget">
    <button class="btn first_btn" id="zufall">zufalls button</button>
    <button class="btn second_btn" id="anmelden">anmelden</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you show us your code, please?

Comment: I edited my question with a code snippet.

Comment: I think you missed the minimal part of [mcve]

Comment: Your snippet is not executable as it is currently (probably missing the jQuery reference)

Comment: To answer to Paulie_D, I've been onto it for a couple of days, and I came here only because I couldn't figure out a solution; I actually DID search Google and SO, but thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRJxVG?editors=1100)

---

The whole section is a `flex` item, vertically centered (with a small  negative `margin-top`). *Ipso facto*, if the content changes, the result is an effect in which the new content placed inside the section pushes all the siblings elements in both the directions.

The `button` just toggles a `.open` class, which runs a CSS animation showing (and hiding) the sibling fieldset (in the markup, the buttons have been defined before the `fieldset`, but they are shown after thanks to the `order` property.

**Markup**

```
<section class="login">
  <h1>Wir suchen noch <br />Frontend-Helden</h1>

  <form>   
    <button type="button" class="login__btt login__btt--zufalls"
            data-collapsed-text="zufalls button"
            data-expandend-text="abbrechen">zufalls button</button>
    <button type="button" class="login__btt login__btt--anmelden">anmelden</button>

    <fieldset class="login__credentials">
      <ul>
        <li>
           <label for="username">User</label>
           <input type="text" id="username" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" />
        </li>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

**CSS** (only relevant, see the demo for the full style)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;  
    font-size: 1.5rem;  
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #9bc, yellowgreen) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 50vh; }


.login {
    width: 500px;
    margin: -20vh auto 0 auto; }


.login form {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #9bc;
    padding: 2em;
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    flex-direction: column; }


.login ul { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; padding: 0; 
    width: 100% }


.login li { 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px; }


.login__btt {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 1em auto;
    order: 1;
    width: 300px;
    padding: .8em 2em;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .65em; }


.login__credentials {
    order: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 260px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 1s .1s, opacity .25s 0s; }


.open ~ .login__credentials {
    transition: height 1s 0s, opacity .5s .5s;
    height: 140px;
    opacity: 1; }
```

**JS**

```
let btt_zufalls = document.querySelector('.login__btt--zufalls');

btt_zufalls.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('open');
    this.textContent = [this.dataset.collapsedText, this.dataset.expandedText][+this.matches('.open')]
});
```

---

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: thank you, I'll try to implement it and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hider").click(function() {
    $("#going_hide").hide();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#shower").click(function() {
    $("#going_hide").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-md-8">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="row" id="going_hide">
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usr">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="going_show">
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="hider">Hide</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="shower">Show</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately id doesn't fit to my problem. Upon opening, it should push down the divs below it, while pushing up those on top of it. Many thanks for the effort though.

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out markup. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer